# Removing consecutive repeated characters from string using C

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm trying to remove consecutive repeated characters from a given string.

Example:

> bssdffFdcrrrtttii        ***#

output is supposed to be:

> bsdfFdcrti *#

This code doesn't work and only prints the first char (b), I want to learn about my mistake.
when I'm doing a printf test, it works but not for spaces.
I think the problem might be with the new char array.

```
void Ex6() {
    char* string[80];
    scanf("%s", &string);
    puts(removeDup(string));
}

char* removeDup(char *string) {
    int i, c = 0;
    char* newString[80];
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        if (string[i] != string[i + 1]) {
            newString[c++] = string[i];
        }
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: What difference do you recognize  between `char* string[80];` and `char string[80];`?  "it works but not for spaces" --> Change `char* string[80];
    scanf("%s", &string);` to `char string[80]; fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);` and _enable all compiler warnings_ to save time.  Report the warnings that are unclear to you.

Comment: There's a huge difference between `char* x`, `char* x[n]` and `char x[n]`, so please be *very careful* when specifying types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with your program:

- The declaration of `newString` should be `char newString[80]`, i.e., an array of characters and not an array of pointers-to-characters, and likewise for the declaration in `Ex6`.
- The call to `scanf` should then be `scanf("%s", string)`, since `string` is already the address of an array of characters, but...
- Use `fgets` to read a string from the user to ensure that you read whitespace, if it's important, and that the buffer is not exceeded.
- `newString` is allocated on the stack and so should not be returned to the caller. It is better to do a `char *newString = strdup(string)`, or, slightly less sloppy, `char *newString = malloc(strlen(string)+1)`, which will call `malloc` for a block of memory sufficient to hold the original string, and thus the version without duplicates -- the comments rightly point out that this could be optimized. In principle, the caller, i.e., `Ex6`, must `free` the returned pointer to avoid a memory leak but it hardly matters in such a short program.
- The result needs a null terminator: `newString[c] = '\0'`.

Otherwise, the `removeDup` function seems to work correctly.

So, putting all of that together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* removeDup(const char *string)
{
    size_t i, c = 0;
    size_t string_len = strlen(string);
    char *newString = malloc(string_len + 1);

    for (i = 0; i < string_len; i++) {
        if (string[i] != string[i + 1]) {
            newString[c++] = string[i];
        }
    }
    newString[c] = '\0';

    return newString;
}

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 80

void Ex6() {
    char string[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    char* result;

    if (fgets(string, MAX_STRING_LEN, stdin) != NULL) {
        result = removeDup(string);

        printf("%s", result);
        free(result);
    }
}
```

Finally, I agree with @tadman's comment. Since the input string must anyway be traversed to calculate the length, we may as well optimize the size of the result string:

```
char* removeDup(const char *string)
{
    size_t i, c = 0;
    char *newString;

    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
        c += (string[i] != string[i + 1]);

    newString = malloc(c + 1);

    for (i = c = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (string[i] != string[i + 1]) {
            newString[c++] = string[i];
        }
    }
    newString[c] = '\0';

    return newString;
}
```

Comment: I don't get a segfault after changing the declaration of `newString` and compiling with `-Wno-return-stack-address` (even though that's not good), but I'm not using `Ex6`.

Comment: You could do one pass to compute how many letters you need, and another with a buffer allocated at the right size.

Comment: @tadman: you're right, but I'm not sure that optimization is worth the trouble. I just wanted to avoid a statically sized string and an allocation on the stack.

Comment: Absolutely! It's just if the string contains a high number of duplicates that could waste a lot of memory, as perhaps the goal of this function is to reduce memory usage. Just adding an observation here, not trying to be overly critical.

Comment: `size_t string_len` is a good improvement.  For consistency (and correctness), `i` and `c` should be the same type `size_t` as `string_len`.

Comment: You should test the return value of `fgets()` to avoid undefined behavior on an empty file. You could also `const` qualify the argument to `removeDup`: `char *removeDup(const char *string)`. Also include `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>` and `<string.h>`.

Comment: @chux: Ok. Thanks for the suggestion. Done.

Comment: @chqrlie: Well spotted (I always forget the error codes and consts). I've updated the code.

Comment: @tadman: you're absolutely right. I've incorporated your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few issues in your program. It wouldn't even compile let alone run. Also, the most problematic issue is that you are returning a pointer to a local variable from a function that ceases its scope upon completion. A simplified version of your program is as follows:

```
void Ex6() 
{
   char string[80];
    scanf("%s", string);
        int i, c = 0;
    char newString[80];
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        if (string[i] != string[i + 1]) {
            newString[c++] = string[i];
        }
    }
    newString[c] = '\0';
    puts(newString);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", string);` retains OP's problem of "it works but not for spaces"

Comment: @chux, thanks for your feedback. I have made corrections.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with O(n) time and O(1) space, by modifying existing string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* removeDup(char* input) {
        char* newTail = input, *oldTail = input;
        while (*oldTail) {
            if (*newTail == *oldTail) {
                ++oldTail;
            } else {
                *++newTail = *oldTail++;
            }
        }
    return newTail;
}

int main() {
   char string[] = "bssdffFdcrrrtttii ***#";
   char* newEnd = removeDup(string);
   char* tmp = string;
   while (tmp != newEnd) {
       printf("%c", *tmp++);
   }
   //Print the last char if string had any duplicates
   if(*tmp) {
       printf("%c", *tmp++);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I agree with this solution, but it depends on the expected interface. Also, your solution is more C++ than C and it may be better to add the null terminator  so that some kind of substr is not required.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, somehow I missed we are dealing with C not C++

Comment: This is one great solution, I would maybe return the first char of the newTail instead of the last, but stil very nice. Oh, also maybe add a \0 in the last non-duplicate char. Great solution, though.